# Android: Toolbar not filling all the space

Tags: android

I've only started learning android recently and I've encountered the following problem:[The toolbar doesn't go all the way](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9HGcW.png)  Here's the code:

**toolbar.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
        app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" >
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            layout="@layout/toolbar" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("");
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.

        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        return true;
    }
}
```

**menu_main.xml**

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="android.example.user.gsmnet.MainActivity"
    app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_home"
        android:orderInCategory="1"
        android:title="Home"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_home"
        app:showAsAction="always" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:orderInCategory="2"
        android:title="Home"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_home"
        app:showAsAction="always" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_cart"
        android:orderInCategory="3"
        android:title="Home"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_home"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_favorites"
        android:orderInCategory="4"
        android:title="Home"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_home"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_user"
        android:orderInCategory="5"
        android:title="Home"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_home"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
</menu>
```

I've tried to remove the app name to make space for the actions (as seen in MainActivity), but only the 2 that have "always" on showAsAction of the 5 show up.

Also, as an extra, could anyone please tell me how to align the actions from left to right?

Comment: Change the others that have `ifRoom` to `always` and see what happens

Comment: They appear, but I need them to only appear if they have room, so that it won't matter on what phone/tablet it's opened on

Answer (score 0):

Menu items to be shown on app bar depends on screen width in dp (density independent pixels )
Below is the link to find reference

https://developer.android.com/design/media/action_bar_pattern_table.png

To confirm this , some of the android phones have 
"Smallest width" option in developer options 
You can edit that, 
Just increase it above 500 and you would be able to see 4 icons visible on action bar

Also you can verify by using an emulator or a phone with higher screen density

By screen density, I mean smallest screen width

Thanks

Comment: Screen density is not the same as screen width

Comment: Screen width is a different term 
Screen width or screen height can be calculated by following formula 
screenWidthInDp =         getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels/getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density

Comment: Yes, Screen density is the number of pixels per inch while screen width is the pixel count from left to right of the device's screen

Comment: Screen width is a different term 

Screen width or screen height can be calculated by following formula 

screenWidthInDp =         getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels/getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density

screenHeightInDp =         getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels/getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density

smallest of screenWidthInDp and screenHeightInDp is considered as Smallest screen width